# Prediction of a bounded variable

Tags: prediction

I have some data on retail stores (it's about 4000x100 entries). I would like to predict  sales volumes potential which is hidden from me. 
I observe some sales volumes which is bounded by sizes of stores (number of salesmans in store, area of a store for example).

Distribution of sales volumes per salesman is looking like this:
[image]

Have you any suggestions, how to solve such kind of problem?